# Twilio setting up help....Cant even run basic apps.....PHP

Tags: php, twilio

This is very disappointing and discouraging...I decided to use Twilio and there is a serious lack of documentation on their website....I am trying to use the Twilio PHP library but I am getting nothing but error and their staff takes hours to reply with vague answers...

Here is my code....I have twilio.php which is the library in same folder as my code but it isnt working just gives errors...Any ideas? I have tried everything I could for past 10 hours just to get a basic script running that uses the php library...

```
<?php



include ('twilio.php')

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/dial_callstatus.xml -->
<Response>
    <Dial action="/handleDialCallStatus.php" method="GET">
        6478804808
    </Dial>
    <Say>I am unreachable</Say>
</Response>


?>
```

Comment: Also, saying "just gives errors" without including those errors is silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you have non-PHP code in your PHP block.

```
<?php include ('twilio.php') ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/dial_callstatus.xml -->
<Response>
    <Dial action="/handleDialCallStatus.php" method="GET">
        6478804808
    </Dial>
    <Say>I am unreachable</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: ERROR: HTTP retrieval failure  
Component: TwiML errors
httpResponse: 500
ErrorCode: 11200


Those people -repping me, if this is such an easy thing to do why dont you make it work? untill then dont trash talk or flame if you dont know the solution to such an "easy" problem

Comment: I've built Twilio apps. It's easy enough if you use valid PHP and read the error messages you get. A HTTP response of 500 means your server is reporting an error, so access the script directly and see what error it's giving.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case, you don't need to include the PHP library at all, just use the XML ([TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/dial_callstatus.xml -->
<Response>
    <Dial action="/handleDialCallStatus.php" method="GET">
        6478804808
    </Dial>
    <Say>I am unreachable</Say>
</Response>
```

You shouldn't need anything else. You only need the PHP library if you're making a request *to* Twilio.